# Why is then not working on this function

Tags: javascript

I tried testing the example given in MDN in one of the promise implementation. Its giving me the error as below.

Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: doSomething(...).then is not a function
    at promise.js:16
```

JS file

```
function successCallback(result) {
    console.log("Success" + result);
}

function failCallback(fail) {
    console.log('fail' + fail);
}

function doSomething(successCallback, failCallback) {
    return "Yello";
};

doSomething(successCallback, failCallback);


doSomething().then(successCallback,failCallback);
```

Comment: There's not promise to be seen in your code.

Comment: You defined a function called doSomething, not a promise

Comment: then what is given in this url?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: The example they show assumes a function that returns a promise, and they contrast it with a function that accepts callbacks. There's nothing magic about promises or functions that return them-it's normal JavaScript, and you still need an object to call "then" on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even easier with *async* :

```
async function doSomething() {
  return "Yello";
};

doSomething().then(console.log);//Yello
```

To enable error handling, simply *throw* an error:

```
async function isMultiple(a,b) {
   if(a%b===0){
      return true;//success
   }
      throw "not a multiple";
};

isMultiple(5,2).then(console.log).catch(console.log);//not a multiple in catch
```

Note that async functions are part of ES7 ( very very new )...

[babeled code](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsI1SAsggGzQAcCBTACmABoAjAShgG8AoGd1OKgUloF4BABnqt2YmACcyyBBKzIJCMgG4A9KpAIoUMiBBt2AXwPjkACwnoA7jABEEdMhjAYAW0Ilyt5S0M-WOPhEqKSUAKzUAEz0AHTmZBBU5BLIsVDAyFBmSWQp9GqqDk4u7sGh2FjpmWZAA)

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to return a Promise which `resolves` in the case of success or `rejects` in case of error to the `then`.

```js
function successCallback(result) {
  console.log("Success" + result);
}

function failCallback(fail) {
  console.log('fail' + fail);
}


function doSomething(successCallback, failCallback) {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      resolve('Yello!');
      // or
      // reject ("Error!");
  });
}

doSomething().then(successCallback, failCallback);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you are not using a `Promise`. To use one, you must do :

```
function successCallback(result) {
    console.log("Success" + result);
}

function failCallback(fail) {
    console.log('fail' + fail);
}

function doSomething() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        console.log("Yello");
        resolve();
    });
}


doSomething().then(successCallback,failCallback);
```

Here, the `failCallback` will never be executed

Answer (score 1):

Your `doSomething` function has to return a `Promise`.
For Example:

`return Promise.resolve('Hello');`

Answer (score 0):

`doSomething` Object does not have `then` function , `doSomething` is just a function

Comment: Then when can we us `then`?

Comment: if we have a 'promise' object like '$http'

Comment: ok then what should I do if I want a promise on a normal function like `do something`

Comment: @user3310115 you return a promise object, which has a then function.

Comment: doSomething  *returns* a string, which has no "then" function. It's irrelevant that doSomething is "just a function", what's relevant is what's returned. This may be what you meant, but the way it's written it's unclear.